# Very slow performance on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu

My laptop is Asus Vivobook E402WA, specs are AMD E2-6110 APU with AMD Radeon R2 Graphics, 4 GB of RAM (actually 3.29 GB are usable), and 5400 RPM hard-disk. As swap partition, I used `zram-tools`, it's set to 730 MB of size, which it is will match the real capacity RAM.

After extensive of customization, my laptop suddenly very slow to operate, which only playing music on YouTube® Music, the CPU usage always hits at 99%. However, RAM usage is good, only about 1.68 GB usage with Firefox and Dolphin launched.

Just want to know, is my CPU too weak to run Kubuntu, or because of many KDE Widgets deployed?

List of KDE Widget Deployed:

- `Folder View`
- `Latte Analog Clock`
- `Simple Weather`
- `Media Player+`, and;
- `Panon`.

For Panels, I used `latte-dock`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IMHO it can be that KDE is too heavy for your PC. I would recommend to move to XFCE (`apt install xubuntu-desktop`). It is lightweight and so mature that it is by far not only recommended for slow PCs.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your suggestions. Then my speculation is completed. KDE use less RAM, but more use CPU, then XFCE use more RAM, but use less CPU.

Comment: Is that your experience? I am surprised that XFCE uses more RAM, but o.k., I never checked that.

Comment: Actually it's from my full experience. I compare some DEs before with Arch Linux, because it's flexible. I tested 3 DEs, first is XFCE, second is Budgie, finally KDE. Then I take a conclusion into this:

Comment: With the setup 2 startup apps, `xdm`, aka. Xtreme Download Manager and `conky`.
> XFCE uses 680 MB RAM on fresh boot, Budgie uses 1.3 GB RAM on fresh boot, and KDE uses 620 MB RAM on fresh boot.

Comment: But I found that heavy DEs such as GNOME or Budgie are actually use less RAM in Debian, which is only uses 850 MB RAM on fresh boot. So the Linux distro is really vary. On Debian, XFCE only use 420 MB RAM on fresh boot, which is really low for 64-bit systems. On 32-bit, XFCE use only 150 MB RAM on fresh boot, which is same par as Lubuntu 18.04, which is really good on very old hardware.